# Custom screen resolution for Android on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am using a [7" TFT LCD Display](https://www.winstar.com.tw/products/tft-lcd/hdmi-tft-lcd/7_0.html) (1024x600) with the Raspberry Pi 3 and I can not make it work with that screen resolution. It looks like it is zoomed in.

I know that there are a bunch of topics about this issue in and out stackoverflow, and I have tried to edit the config.txt as much as I could, never getting different results. (BTW: I got it working with Raspian really easily editing the config.txt, but it does not work for android for some reason).

I used [this Android image](https://howtoraspberrypi.com/install-android-raspberry-pi/), and this is how my config.txt looks like:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_drive=2
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 1024 600 60
Framebuffer_width=1024
Framebuffer_height=600
disable_overscan=1
config_hdmi_boost=5
kernel=zImage
device_tree=bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb
dtparam=audio=on
dtparam=i2c1=on
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d,cma-256
initramfs ramdisk.img 0x01f00000
mask_gpu_interrupt0=0x400
avoid_warnings=2
gpu_mem=256
enable_uart=1
```

I would really appreciate some insight on this.

PS: I tried different resolutions with the *hdmi_group* and *hdmi_mode*, according to [this RPi article](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md), but the image remains the same.

Comment: Maybe you should ask on [raspberrypi.se]?

Comment: Thanks for the tip @iBug, I will. But, just so I know, is this kind of question not appropriate here? I'm new here...

Comment: This question is not related to programming but configuring specific hardware, so it's off-topic here. It's better on its dedicated site. You can get more RPi-oriented answers there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got it working by trial and error, and I posted the [answer in the RaspberryPi Stackexchange site](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/82686/custom-screen-resolution-for-android-on-raspberry-pi-3/82713#82713) as suggested. Case closed for now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same 'zoomed in' effect using Android Studio (React-Native) with an 800*480 HDMI screen (Waveshare 5-inch).  When I used Dimensions, within the app, to get the screen size, it returned approx 530 * 300, which had the additional effect of changing the bucket size for images being copied over from the assets folder.  My solution, found after some considerable time, was from Dokter_Bibber at this [link](https://discuss.96boards.org/t/hdmi-disabled-in-android-how-to-enable/3849/10).  It did not give me precisely the same display as my 800*480 Android-Studio-emulator that I was using to develop my page, but pleasingly close.

Quoting from the link:

Start Console window and type :

adb shell wm size 800x480

---AND (186.59 ppi calculated here : https://www.sven.de/dpi/ 4)

adb shell wm density 187

THEN (reboot the device)

adb reboot